# Count Nodes who have two same sons

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I need to write operation that count nodes who have two sons that equal each other. I tried to  it but i got error that not all code path return a value.
please help i have a test
Thanks.

```
public static int CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(BinNode<int> Head)
{
        if (Head != null)
        {
            if (IsLeaf(Head))
                return 1;

            if ((Head.HasLeft() && Head.HasRight()) && (Head.GetRight() == Head.GetLeft()))
                return 1 + CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetLeft()) + CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetRight());
        }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        BinNode<int> t = new BinNode<int>(3);
        BinNode<int> t1 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        BinNode<int> t2 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        BinNode<int> t3 = new BinNode<int>(3);
        BinNode<int> t4 = new BinNode<int>(t,3,t1);
        BinNode<int> t5 = new BinNode<int>(t2,3,t3);
        BinNode<int> t6 = new BinNode<int>(t4,3,null);
        BinNode<int> Head = new BinNode<int>(t6,3,t5);
        Console.WriteLine(SumTree(Head));
        Console.WriteLine(LeafCounter(Head));
        Console.WriteLine(CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head));

        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a return outside an If statement, the compiler can't work out if this function will return something or not. If you can just add a return statement at the end of the function that returns a 0 it should work. Not the most prefered fix, you should really rewrite the function so the return actually is more than just a way of pleasing the compiler but it should work.

Danny

Comment: What Santiago Varela said. I didn't see your answer before starting on mine.

Answer (score 0):

As your error states, your current function may not have return statements in some instances.

```
public static int CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(BinNode<int> Head)
 {
        if (Head == null)
            return 0;
        if (IsLeaf(Head))
            return 1;
        if ((Head.HasLeft() && Head.HasRight()) &&
           (Head.GetRight() == Head.GetLeft()))  // It happens with this if statement!
              return 1 + CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetLeft()) + 
              CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetRight());

 }
```

The error "not all paths return a value" is correct. If your execution flow gets to the third if statement and it is false, then there is no value returned. Your function is defined to always return an `int` and that case is not being contemplated.

So, try something like this to fix it:

```
public static int CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(BinNode<int> Head)
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
        if (IsLeaf(Head))
            return 1;

        if (Head.HasLeft() && Head.HasRight())
        {
            if (Head.GetRight().GetValue() == Head.GetLeft().GetValue()))
                return 1 + CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetLeft()) + CountWhoHasTwoSameSons(Head.GetRight());    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i edited the question , it return 0 for it (see the main)

Comment: How are your BinTree objects connected to Head? How do you specify the root of the tree? Do LeafCounter(Head) and SumTree(Head) work?

Comment: The error "not all code paths return a value"is fixed though, right?

Comment: I know. That's why I'm asking if your other functions work? Because on your main(), I don't see how Head is connected to you BinTrees

Comment: You may be passing Head in as null to the Function somehow.

Comment: with else it not work , got the first error. i think i have problem with the main , can you please take a look in the main , maybe the nodes are not connected each other

Comment: it work with add .GetValue() Thank you very much , you are the best!

Comment: Glad to help buddyhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019896/count-nodes-who-have-two-same-sons/43019919#comment73128619_43019919 :) Teamwork! Please upvote and mark correct.